# How to search include headers out of package path in bazel

Tags: bazel

In the `cc_library` how do I specify `hdrs` and `includes` when the path is outside the package?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your header file outside of the package is named `logging.h` and contained in a folder named `core`.
You can introduce an own BUILD file (package) for this file and make it visible, e.g.:

```
# in the core folder
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(

    name = "logging",
    hdrs = [
        "logging.h",
    ],
)
```

Now if you want to make use of this file in another package, e.g.

```
# somewhere else
cc_library(
    hdrs = ["somewhere_else.h"],
    deps = [
        "//core:logging",   # reference the dependency to logging.h
    ],
)
```

In the header file `somwhere_else.h` you can include now:

```
#include "core/logging.h"
```